# Quadric surfaces tangent to a cubic threefold along a line of first type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hypersurfaces

Take a line $L$ of the first type on a smooth cubic threefold $X$ over $\mathbb C$, then its normal bundle $N_{L|X}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_L\oplus \mathcal{O}_L$. This is equivalent to say that there is a $\mathbb P^1$-family of quadric surfaces in $\mathbb P^4$ tangent to $X$ along $L$. I'm trying to write down these quadric surfaces explicitly.

Let $L=\{x_2=x_3=x_4=0\}$, then up to change of coordinates, $X$ has equation

$$x_2x_0^2+x_3x_0x_1+x_4x_1^2+\text{higher order terms in }x_2,x_3,x_4.$$

The dual map at $p={(x_0,x_1)}\in L$ is $\mathcal{D}(p)=[0,0,x_0^2,x_0x_1,x_1^2]$, which determines the hyperplane $T_{p}X$ at $p$ and we just need to find quadric surfaces containing $L$ and have tangent planes at each $p\in L$ contained in $T_{p}X$.

I can find two of such quadric surfaces:

$$x_4=0,~x_2x_0+x_3x_1=0,$$
$$x_2=0,~x_4x_1+x_3x_0=0.$$

Unfortunately, the family is not a linear combination of them and I cannot find any more such quadric surface. Note that in the 1972 paper *The intermediate Jacobian of the cubic threefolds* by Clemens and Griffiths, page 309, some constructions are given in terms of equations of varieties of lines of the quadric surfaces in the Grassmannian $Gr(2,5)$. However, there seems to be a typo in the defining equations (of curve $B(\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$ in the paper), which I couldn't fix.

How to find the entire $\mathbb P^1$-family (hopefully in equations)? Any comments or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: How do you conclude that there is a $\mathbb{P}^1$-family of quadric surfaces in $\mathbb{P}^4$ tangent to $X$ along $L$?

Comment: Dear @Sasha, as the normal bundle $N_{L|X}$ is $\mathcal{O}_L\oplus \mathcal{O}_L$, the image of any nonzero section $s$ is a line in $\mathbb P^4$ which is disjoint from $L$ and union of family of disjoint lines $\cup_{0\le t\le 1}ts(L)$ is Zariski dense in a quadric surface, whose tangent spaces along $L$ are contained in $TX$. Two sections determine the same quadric surface if and only if one is a multiple to the other, so there is a $\mathbb PH^0(N_{L|X})\cong \mathbb P^1$-family of such quadric surfaces. Actually, I can find these equations now. I'll write a solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my question is all about linear algebra. As I mentioned in the chat, to find such a quadric surface, one needs to find a line $L'$ in $\mathbb P^4$, which lies in the normal direction of $L$ inside the cubic threefold $X$. Such a line is the image of a nonzero section $s$ in the normal bundle $N_{L|X}\cong \mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}$ and the quadric surface is determined by the family of disjoint lines $\cup_{t\in \mathbb C}ts(L)$.

In other words, by linearizing the local equation of the Fano variety of lines $F$ of $X$ in the Grassmannian $Gr(2,5)$ (i.e., throw out higher-order terms in 6.14 in Clemens-Griffiths), we can determine that the equation of $L'_t=ts(L)$ is

$$
    \begin{cases}
    tax_1+x_2=0,\\
    tbx_0-x_4=0,\\
    tax_0-tbx_1-x_3=0.
    \end{cases}\tag{1}\label{1}
    $$

with $(a,b)\in \mathbb P^1$. By standard linear algebra, we cancel out $t$ and find that the $\mathbb P^{1}$-family of quadric surfaces are given by

$$
    \begin{cases}
    \text{I}.~a^2x_4+b^2x_2-abx_3=0,\\
    \text{II}.~ax_2x_0+ax_3x_1-bx_2x_1=0,\\
    \text{III}. ~ax_4x_0-bx_4x_1-bx_3x_0=0.
    \end{cases}\tag{2}\label{2}
    $$

in $\mathbb P^1_{[a,b]}\times \mathbb P^4_{[x_0,...,x_4]}$, with one linear equation and two quadric equations. Note that the family is not a complete intersection: When $a\neq 0$, the equation $\text{III}$ is redundant while when $b\neq 0$, the equation $\text{II}$ is redundant. Moreover, the points $(a,b)=(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ correspond to the two "obvious" quadric surfaces that mentioned in the question.

By the way, I finally fixed the typo in Clemens-Griffiths p.309, about the defining equation of the curve $B(\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$: the fourth equation should be `u_5=\cdots=u_n=z_4=\cdots=z_n=0`. (The original paper has a `z_2` instead of `z_4`, which is wrong.) It turns out that the 1-parameter family of lines in Clemens-Griffiths is exactly the family $(\ref{1})$ we defined and $(\ref{2})$ are the explicit equations for
the $\mathbb P^1$-family of quadric surfaces tangent to $X$ along $L$ mentioned in Lemma 6.18.